# How to increment values at the same time rather than mapping through them in order?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapping, simultaneous

I am making a racing game in ReactJS and I need to increment the values of four race entities (divs in my case) at the same time, rather than mapping through them and incrementing them one by one. Right now they all increment on button click at random speed.

```
changePlayerArr.map(player => {
  console.log(player)
  player.speed = player.speed - Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 + 5)
});
```

They move by VW in CSS and the goal is to get them to -100vw which is the end of the screen. However, I can't know which one is the real winner if I increment their speeds from the first div to last div or vice versa. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't know which the real winner is?

Comment: @jz22 Let's say I have to divs that increment their vw value on button click randomly by 5-15vw. So when the race starts on button click they get 5-15vw and they are trying too reach 70vw which is the finish line. Lets say the second div is at 69vw (1 vw away from finish) and the first is at 60vw. On next button click they increment by 5-15 randomly. So for instance the second one goes to 75vw and the first to 70vw. Since the mapping checks the first div first, it's going to increment it first and the winner will be the first div even if it was slower than the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is single-threaded, not much in the way of concurrency. I think about the best you can do is to keep a structure of some metric that matters to the racing players (displacement for example) and apply a displacement accumulator (`displacementDelta = rate * time`) upon each render cycle to determine a new sorted order.

The winner could be the element in first place (index 0 maybe?) after accumulating displacement and sorting the structure *after at least one* element achieves the racing distance.